# Call TFS API from non on-premise service

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I want to call the TFS Rest API

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/rest/basics#tfs

from an application that isn't on-premise with that instance of TFS (it'll be in Azure to be specific).  Is that possible?  Anything special needed to configure a cloud service to call on-premise?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, you need to make sure your TFS can be accessible from cloud or another server.

[There](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668967.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is an article about providing internet access to TFS that can help you.

Comment: thanks for the link.  Led to some more googling.  Sounds like it's possible but may be a bit of a pain.  Sidenote: you've been helpful on some of my VSTS/TFS API questions.  How are you so familiar with them?

Comment: @scottndecker Do more practice is the better way to learn something.